# Ridge on mesh after curve modifier

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have modeling a mesh and then I want to curve it to fit another mesh.
But when I am using the curve modifier, some ridges appears on the mesh :
[image] 
What can I do to avoid this ? I tried to multiply the number of faces using subdivision surface, but there is 6M faces on the mesh from the photo and so don't working.

Comment: hello, your problem is probably your mesh topology, but too hard to say with so few informations

Comment: If the problem com from the topology, a lot of vertices is not enought to counter it ?

Comment: please share your file or at least a screenshot of your mesh, we don't know enough about it

Comment: https://files.fm/u/j68rswa3
Here is the blender file with all the steps of the mesh

Comment: "*a lot of vertices is not enought to counter it ?*" A lot of vertices are probably what is causing the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nicolas, your topology is not good, too many vertices and you won't have anything good when you'll twist this shape, so go back to a simpler version of your mesh, and begin to build a good topology (not sure it's the best but it's better for sure):

[image]

PS: if you're french, join us on Blenderclan http://blenderclan.tuxfamily.org/html/modules/newbb/

Comment: Okay I understund where was the problem, full thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

More vertices are most definitely not "better" topology. I'd recommend [this blog](https://topologyguides.com/) about the topology topic.

In your case it would be best to start from scratch. If you want to use what you have got, you only need to keep the outline.

1. Select the outer edge loop with <kbd>Alt</kbd> rightclick and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> right click.
   Invert the selection. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>
   Delete all selected vertices. <kbd>X</kbd> > *Vertices*
   [image]
2. Then, convert your mesh to a curve with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > Mesh to Curve.
   Set the curve to *2D* and use its extrude features to give the flat surface depth.
   [image]

Comment: I am sorry if I sayd it the wrong way, but I don't want to make a curve from the mesh, it's the opposite, I made the mesh from curve (easier for me with all the curve inside the model) and now I just want to curve the mesh on the circle, to fit the shape of the circle and it's when I apply the curve modifier on the model basing on the circle, that some ridges appears